# Set condition on PXSelector to filter fields based on the value from another table

Tags: selector, acumatica

I have a selector field where I am trying to show only the child field with the same detailNoteID as the parent document NoteID in the selector.
These are the 2 fields I am working with. The line on the bottom is what I am trying to do.
[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2wi3.png)

```
    [PXDBInt()]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Document Type")]
    [PXSelector(typeof(Search<DMDocType.documentID, Where<DMDocType.isActive, Equal <True>>>),
    typeof(DMDocType.documentCD),
    typeof(DMDocType.description),
    ValidateValue = false,
    DescriptionField = typeof(DMDocType.description),
    SubstituteKey = typeof(DMDocType.description))]  
    [PXDefault(PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.NullOrBlank)]      
    public virtual int? DocumentType { get; set; }
    public abstract class documentType : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<documentType> { }
    #endregion

    #region DocumentCategory
    [PXDBInt()]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Document Category")]
    [PXSelector(typeof(Search<DMDocCategory.documentID, Where<DMDocCategory.docTypeID, Equal<Current<documentType>>
     , And<DMDocCategory.isActive, Equal <True>>>>),
    typeof(DMDocCategory.description),
    SubstituteKey = typeof(DMDocCategory.description))]       
    public virtual int? DocumentCategory { get; set; }
    public abstract class documentCategory : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<documentCategory> { }
     #endregion

This is what I am looking for.

[PXSelector(typeof(Search<DMDocCategory.documentID, Where<DMDocCategory.detailNoteID, Equal<Current<DMDocType.noteID>>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Search2 that enables you to join tables. Something like this:

```
[PXSelector(typeof(Search2<DMDocCategory.documentID, InnerJoin<DMDocType, On<DMDocCategory.detailNoteID, Equal<DMDocType.noteID>>>, Where<DMDocType.noteID, Equal<Current<DMDocType.noteID>>>>))]
```

There are also other variations such as Search3, Search4 etc. that give you further options to order by, aggregate, etc.